# How to make an ArrayList of enemy objects in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift3, sprite-kit

I’m trying to code a game in swift and I want to be able to keep track of enemy position, Heath, and such. Like in Java it’s as easy as declaring an array list of type, say, enemy and then filling it with a forloop or when ever I want to add an enemy. But I’ve looked absolutely everywhere for help on the subject and I’m not finding what I need for my game to work. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: You don’t really want an array of enemies. Instead use a subclass of SKSpriteNode and have each instance of an enemy track its own health.  Position is a property of a sprite so you don’t have to track that either. Unless you have a very real reason for keeping each enemy in your own array, there is the `children` array as a property of the scene or you can use `enumerateChildNodes` to process all nodes matching your criteria. Lastly, for collision and contact event, Sprike-Kit will pass you pointers to the sprites involved.

Comment: I guess I don't fully understand how to go about this. If you could point me to a good example of this or post one, that would be super helpful. Thank you again

Comment: SO isn't a tutorial site, but there are some excellent Sprite-Kit tutorials at www.raywenderlich.com. If you are serious, I recommend his 2D Apple Games book with examples for about $50.

Answer (score 2):

Swift has collections just like Java. You could create an array of the objects, like so:

```
var someInts = [Int]()
someInts.append(3)
```

Using the example, change `Int` for the type of the enemy object. You would then need to iterate using a for loop to retrieve (or store) any more objects.

More information on Swift collections are here (also includes how to iterate through them):

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html